# Oracle: What is "(+) ="?

Tags: oracle11g

I don't currently have any access to any Oracle books and my searches online are returning literally no results ( (+) in Google shows nothing).  I'm looking through existing code to add some fields to a query and saw:

```
AND lookup.LookupID (+) = AuditID
```

However, I have no idea what this does.  Any help would be appreciated.

Note:  I'm not seeing a community wiki checkbox while posting this in Google Chrome, so if someone can change it to that for me, I'd be appreciative.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is Oracle way to specify a outer join (ANSI way would be RIGHT JOIN/LEFT JOIN)

Comment: Yes the oracle way goes in a where clause instead of the tables specification

Comment: If you don't like using the (+), you can still use the ANSI style of INNER/LEFT/RIGHT JOIN :)

Answer (score 7):

What you're seeing is an "old" way for specifying an outer join. Oracle needed a syntax to represent outer joins and before the ANSI commitee settled on a standard syntax, Oracle came up with their own.

`(+)` should be seen only in legacy code and today it is recommended to simply avoid this syntax and stick with the standards.

In this [Oracle FAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/node/855) you can read some historical info. Not too detailed, but it will give you an idea of how this operator came to be.

Relevant part:

> In query2 we see the "Old Style"
>   Oracle syntax for OUTER-JOIN. It is
>   the PLUS SIGN in parenthesis. This
>   syntax was not actually invented by
>   Oracle but rather some smart guy whose
>   name escapes me at the moment. Oracle
>   saw its value and was an early adopter
>   of OUTER-JOIN but doing so required
>   them to use a syntax before ANSI SQL
>   COMMITTEE settled on one. The new and
>   improved ANSI SQL is fine and all,
>   some say even better, but being an old
>   bird I tend to stick with old and
>   proven ways till something makes me
>   change.

Apparently not even Oracle did invent this syntax. It's good to have standards...